# How can I give a variable batch_dim in output_shape argument of deconv2d in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deconvolution

I am trying to use the `tf.nn.deconv2d()` op on a variable-sized batch of data. However, it appears that I need to set the `output_shape` argument as follows:

```
tf.nn.deconv2d(x, filter, output_shape=[12, 24, 24, 5], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
               padding="SAME")
```

Why does `tf.nn.deconv2d()` take a fixed `output_shape`? Is there any way to specify a variable batch dimension? What happens if the input batch size varies?

Answer (score 5):

**N.B.** `tf.nn.deconv2d()` will be called [`tf.nn.conv2d_transpose()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d_transpose) in the next release of TensorFlow (0.7.0).

The `output_shape` argument to `tf.nn.deconv2d()` accepts a computed `Tensor` as its value, which enables you specify a dynamic shape. For example, let's say your input is defined as follows:

```
# N.B. Other dimensions are chosen arbitrarily.
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 24, 24, 5])
```

...then the batch size for a particular step can be computed at runtime:

```
batch_size = tf.shape(input)[0]
```

With this value, you can then build the `output_shape` argument to `tf.nn.deconv2d()` using [`tf.pack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pack):

```
output_shape = tf.pack([batch_size, 24, 24, 5])

result = tf.nn.deconv2d(..., filter, output_shape=output_shape,
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: In r0.12 tf.pack() has been deprecated, tf.stack() is the proper usage as per the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#pack