# Tensorflow conv2d_transpose (deconv) Number of rows of out_backprop doesn't match computed

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

**EDIT** My issue is the width and height of my filter, I misunderstood the API doc... working on correction now

**SOLUTION** Follow deconvolution from [here](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/winter1516_lecture13.pdf) slide 53

---

I have a similar issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967872/tensorflow-conv2d-transpose-size-error-number-of-rows-of-out-backprop-doesnt-m) but it's a little funkier.

My error is `Conv2DBackpropInput: Number of rows of out_backprop doesn't match computed: actual = 25, computed = 26` at the time of the optimizer initialization.

...so it's off by 1?

Some background...

I have a conv layer with dimensions `<tf.Tensor 'MaxPool_2:0' shape=(?, 25, 25, 128) dtype=float32>`

The input image is 200x200, and I have 3 maxpool layers -- thus the h = w = 25. I want to add 3 deconv layers so that I return the original resolution (I'm doing image segmentation).

The deconv code looks like:

```
temp_batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
# output_shape = tf.pack([temp_batch_size, 50, 50, 64])
output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 50, 50, 64]
conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv3, weights['wdc1'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="VALID")
# conv4 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv4)

# output_shape = tf.pack([temp_batch_size, 100, 100, 32])
output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 100, 100, 32]
conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv4, weights['wdc2'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="VALID")
# conv5 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv5)

# output_shape = tf.pack([temp_batch_size, 200, 200, 1])
output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 200, 200, 1]
conv6 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv5, weights['wdc3'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="VALID")
# conv6 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv6)
```

(You can see I tried to `tf.pack()` to no success -- as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346599/how-can-i-give-a-variable-batch-dim-in-output-shape-argument-of-deconv2d-in-tens)) Where the weights are:

```
'wdc1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([25, 25, 64,128])),

'wdc2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([50, 50, 32,64])),

'wdc3' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 100, 1,32])),
```

Some debugging looks like this:

```
(Pdb) conv3
<tf.Tensor 'MaxPool_2:0' shape=(?, 25, 25, 128) dtype=float32>
(Pdb) conv4
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_transpose:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, ?) dtype=float32>
(Pdb) conv5
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_transpose_1:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, ?) dtype=float32>
(Pdb) conv6
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_transpose_2:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, ?) dtype=float32>
```

I find it odd that because I have the line `temp_batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]` (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346599/how-can-i-give-a-variable-batch-dim-in-output-shape-argument-of-deconv2d-in-tens)), the last 3 dimensions are also question marks? If I change the first dimension to a constant (such as 10) I get `<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_transpose:0' shape=(10, 50, 50, 64) dtype=float32>`

So maybe that is part of my issue? If I change it back to a constant `batch_size` then I get the error `ValueError: Shapes (10, 101, 101, 32) and (10, 100, 100, 32) are not compatible` at the time of the optimizer initialization. Once again, off by one.

Debugging with this configuration...

```
(Pdb) conv4
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_transpose:0' shape=(10, 50, 50, 64) dtype=float32>
(Pdb) conv5
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_transpose_1:0' shape=(10, 100, 100, 32) dtype=float32>
(Pdb) conv6
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_transpose_2:0' shape=(10, 200, 200, 1) dtype=float32>
```

Is the issue my number of strides? What should they be (I've tried different variations to no success)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using transposed convolutions, you need to think backwards: how would you get your input (`conv3` of shape `[batch_size, 25, 25, 128]`) given the output (of shape `[batch_size, 200, 200, 1]`)?

You would do a succession of 3x3 convolutions and max pooling. Unfortunately, unpooling is not yet available in TensorFlow, so you will just have transposed convolutions.

The filters should have **normal CNN shapes**: like 3x3 convolutions, or 5x5. If you want to increase the output size, you need to use strided transpose convolutions.

```
weights = {
  'wdc1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 64, 128])),
  'wdc2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 64])),
  'wdc3' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 32]))
}
```

And the code (don't forget the stride = 2):

```py
temp_batch_size = 10

conv3 = tf.zeros([temp_batch_size, 25, 25, 128])
output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 50, 50, 64]
conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv3, weights['wdc1'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")

output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 100, 100, 32]
conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv4, weights['wdc2'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")

output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 200, 200, 1]
conv6 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv5, weights['wdc3'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")
```

---

**EDIT:**

Just saw your edit. The [slides](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/winter1516_lecture13.pdf) from CS231n are a very good illustration of how to use transposed convolutions, it's even better with the [video](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/4hqwza/andrej_karpathy_forced_to_take_down_stanford/) !

Comment: Thanks Olivier! This is exactly what I did!

Comment: btw, don't forget the ReLUs